# Watson Assistant slot regular expression for a name or text without numbers

Tags: regex, watson-conversation

I want to capture the first name and second name using slots in Watson Assistant by prompting.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#creating-entities

gives regular expressions for phone, email, and website.

What is the regular expression for the simple names like John, Tara, McKinsey etc?

Comment: There are many examples of character-only expressions available. Many people have more complex names. If you know that a string only has two parts, split the input.

Comment: What would be the exact regular expression that I can use in Watson for a string that has only capital and small English alphabets?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@sys-name` entity type slots from `system-entities` in your dialogue. Look at using slots. [using slots](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-slots.html)

Comment: "@sys-name" is not available during autocomplete. But I gave it anyway. It does not recognize the name "Siju". It keeps on asking the name again and again. Does "@sys-name" recognize only a set of predefined names?